# Using if else in For Loop increment

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, increment

I have a problem in Java:

> Given a string, return a string made of the chars at indexes 0,1,4,5,8,9...

I know how to solve it, however I was wondering if it's possible for me to use `if-else` in for-loop increment itself, for example:

```
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); if (i%4==0) i++, else i+=3){
    result += str.charAt(i);
}
```

Can we do something like that?

Comment: Such a thing obfuscates your code. You'd be better off making the assignment conditional, not the `for` loop increment.

Comment: To whoever answered suggesting me to leave increment blank and then put `if-else` in loop body but later deleted answer, I just wanted to thank you; I've never thought about that before.

Comment: Yes I am aware that it would make code "ugly," I was just curious about a way to struct something; even if it's unnecessary. But thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: It's not so much out of ugliness, but out of maintainability and readability. A perfect piece of code would have you say "Ah, I immediately understand what's going on."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't use an if there but you can use a ternary operator

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += i%4 == 0 ? 1 : 3) {
    result += str.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be done

Comment: _Increment expression_ has to increment or decrement a loop control variable value - so it should be along the language recommendation.

Answer (score 9):

Putting it simply, you want two characters from every 4<sup>th</sup> position starting from 0. You can use the following code for that:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < safeLength; i += 4){
    builder.Append(str.substring(i, i + 2));
}
```

Unlike the answer that you have accepted, in this answer there is:

- *no obfuscation;*
- *the intent is very clear;* and,
- ***most importantly***, no `if-else` or ternary operator.

---

**Update:** I'm aware of the possibility of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but because I wanted to keep the attention on core logic only, I didn't add that check. Here is the code that needs to be added to avoid the exceptional cases:

Put following code above the for loop:

```
int safeLength = str.Length();
bool lengthCorrectionWasNeeded = (str.length() - 1) % 4 == 0;
if (lengthCorrectionWasNeeded) safeLength--;
```

Put following code below the for loop:

```
if (lengthCorrectionWasNeeded) builder.append(str.substring(str.length() - 2));
```

At the end `builder.ToString()` will contain the desired string.

Comment: Your for loop is much better but your solution will give a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for some inputs

Comment: @VBCPP: Instead of leaving the comments here, I thought I would just update the answer. So, there you go.

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty much what my original solution was, but without `StringBuilder`. Never seen it, so I take that I should use it if I'm going to modify single string a lot?

Comment: @micahwood50: Yes, you should use `StringBuilder` if there is going to be a lot of string based addition-subtraction. And you should definitely read this [Sad Tragedy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) and [Horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 8):

As for the issue "Using if else in For Loop increment", I agree with Manos's answer.
The following are some of my suggestion.
In my opinion, it is important that codes are clear and clean.
And it is a good practice that extract `str.length()` to a local variable instead of 'calculating' it in every loop.
And if you are building a string by appending it lots of time, StringBuilder is a good choice.

```
    String str = "this is your string ...";
    int length = str.length();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i += (i%4 == 0 ? 1 : 3)){
       builder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use StringBuilder. Calling `str.length()` on each iteration however isn't a performance issue. This method just returns the length property of the underlying `char[]` and it's very likely to be inlined. It's not "calculating" anything.